# What alternative authentication libraries/frameworks exist for ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication, forms-authentication

I'm building my own authentication module(to sell, hopefully) and I'm wondering what my competition is. What alternative authentication libraries exist other than Windows/Forms Authentication? I'm looking especially for frameworks that were not produced by Microsoft.

To be specific, I'm talking about authentication methods with .Net libraries that store user credentials(username/password hash) in your own database.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's openid, oauth, facebook, and whatever else you want to do.

Honestly, it sounds like you're creating a solution in search of a problem.  There are already so many different, and free, authentication systems out there.  Why would anyone want to pay for yours?  What makes your unique?  What makes your desirable over anyone elses?

EDIT:

Most people who just need a username/password stored in a database, they find the standard Membership and Role Providers to be more than adequate.  They're fairly simple, and work well.  That doesn't usually leave much impetus to design something new.

What does your library do that Membership/Role Provider doesn't?

Comment: Those are all external authentication services. I'm talking about where you store the user credentials on your own server. Currently, Forms Authentication or rolling your own seems to be the only options(the only I see anyway, hence this question). So I rolled my own and I think it's pretty awesome, so I want to fill that bit of a niche with it.

Comment: @Earlz - Then I suggest you clarify your question. You made no mention of "external" or "internal" in your question, and it's very vague. At this point, I have no idea what answer you're looking for, or even what the real question is. There really is no difference between an internal and external authentication anyways, they ultimately do the same thing, just in different ways. This is the basis behind Windows Identity Foundation.  Authentication should be a black box that the app has no knowledge of.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Identity_Foundation

Comment: Possibly I mean authorization instead of authentication. But basically all of the "many different and free authentication systems out there" what are they? And I mean systems with .Net libraries and that store username/password(hash) in your own database. I don't see why you're having so much difficulty understanding me

Comment: @Earlz - Because you're not asking any real questions.  Notice that nobody else has answered you either, that's usually a good indication that your question is not clear enough.  It may seem simple and easy to you, because you understand what you want to know.  You're not communicating it clearly enough to anyone else.  Authorization and Authentication are different concepts, though they are related.  Authorization has so many different ways it can be implemented, from page level to field level and varying stages in between.